# Total ROW Mysql C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database table called `nama`:

```
id | tomi | asep | andre |
--------------------------
1  | 123  | 321  | 545   |
```

When I use the following SQL query:

```
select * from nama;
```

I get this output:

```
1 123 321 545
```

That's 4 columns in total.

How can I get the total columns in C# with MySQL?

Comment: it has only 1 row with four columns

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Do you want to know how to:
Return the number of rows?
Return the number of columns?
Return the SUM/(total) values for a column or columns?

Comment: sory edit, that total 4 columns.
how to get total columns in c# with Mysql

Answer (score 2):

A simple example can be :

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "select * from nama;";

MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable tblNama = new DataTable();
tblNama.Load(reader);

int numR = tblNama.Rows.Count; //Number of Rows ...
int numC = tblNama.Columns.Count; //Number of Columns ...
```

Comment: Glad to know, anyway you should read the rules here on StackOverflow ... :-)